# Timing response time from server

Tags: c, time, udp

I'm working on a UDP client that sends a message to a server. I also need to calculate the RTT (Round Trip Time) in microseconds. I have two variables (t1, t2) that I'd like to store these times in. t1 is used when a message is sent to the server and t2 is used just after the client receives the message. I then would like to call a function like `difftime(t1,t2);` to display this time difference. I have `#include <time.h>` as a preprocessor but I do not know what data types I should use for t1 and t2. In Googling the time.h man page I saw something what looks like a data type called `suseconds_t` (which, if I understand correctly, is similar to using `time_t`), but I'm not sure how to use it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `struct timeval` and `gettimeofday()` for this.

```
struct timeval t1, t2;

gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
// send packet and receive response
gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
```

Then you can use a function like this to calculate the difference:

```
struct timeval diff_timeval(struct timeval t2, struct timeval t1)
{
    struct timeval result;

    result.tv_sec = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;      // subtract seconds
    result.tv_usec = t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec;   // subtract microseconds
    // microsecond result could be negative, ex. 2.1 - 1.9 = 1 sec - 800000 microseconds
    // if so, subtract one second and add 1000000 microseconds
    while (result.tv_usec < 0) {
        result.tv_usec += 1000000;
        result.tv_sec--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried using `gettimeofday()` but I was doing something like `t1 = gettimeofday();` An error on compilation that I'm getting is that `the storage space of 'result' is unknown` on the declaration of result. Also, in the while loop, why are we checking the condition to be `tv_usec < 0` when we increment it the next line?

Comment: **CORRECTION OF ABOVE COMMENT** I just misspelled `struct timeval result` so it threw me errors.

Comment: @TravisPatterson  See updated answer regarding the negative check.

Comment: Then to printf the results is what? currently I'm trying `printf("RTT time is %e\n", diff_timeval(t2,t1);` but that's giving me a value of like 4E-310

Comment: The function returns a `struct timeval`.  The `tv_sec` field is seconds and the `tv_usec` field is microseconds.  So you would print it as `printf("RTT time is %d.%06d\n", result.tv_sec, result.tv_usec)`, where `result` is the return value of the function.

Comment: So I put the printf statement within the `diff_timeval()` function but using the formatting options that you suggested just gives me an RTT of 0.000000 (I'm guessing that it's not quite precise enough)